# Apply class to img via custom jQuery dropdown

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a little editor where I'd like to be able to right click on an image, and then do something to it.

I have the custom right click menu working, but I don't know how to tell jQuery which item I've right clicked on.

jsFiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/kthornbloom/YsW8D/1/

Code:

```
// Make the menu
$('.something img').bind("contextmenu", function(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();
    $("div.custom-menu").hide();
    $('<div class="custom-menu"><a href="#" class="fr">Float Right</a></div>')
        .appendTo("body")
        .css({top: event.pageY + "px", left: event.pageX + "px"});
});
// Remove the menu
$(document).bind("click", function(event) {
    $("div.custom-menu").hide();
    event.preventDefault();
});

// Apply option to image you right-clicked on
$(document.body).on("click", ".run", function (event) {
    // this won't work, but is what I want to happen.
    $(this).nearest('img').addClass('float-right');
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[this](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/) inside the handler method refers the element which is targeted by the event handler

```
$('.something img').bind("contextmenu", function(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();

    //this refers to the clicked element
    console.log(this)
    $("div.custom-menu").hide();
    $('<div class="custom-menu"><a href="#" class="fr">Float Right</a></div>')
        .appendTo("body")
        .css({top: event.pageY + "px", left: event.pageX + "px"});
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Rxqt8/)
Since you want to know the target element in context menu handlers, I would suggest you save the clicked element reference for future reference. jQuery provides a very good option for doing this using [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data)

UPDATE

```
// Make the menu
$('.something img').bind("contextmenu", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("div.custom-menu").remove();
    $('<div class="custom-menu"><a href="#" class="fr">Float Right</a></div>')
        .appendTo("body")
        .css({
        top: event.pageY + "px",
        left: event.pageX + "px"
    }).data('target', this);
});
// Remove the menu
$(document).bind("click", function (event) {
    $("div.custom-menu").remove();
    event.preventDefault();
});

// Apply option to image you right-clicked on
$(document.body).on("click", ".fr", function (event) {
    var $target = $($(this).closest('.custom-menu').data('target'));
    $target.addClass('float-right');
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9Zrw9/)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Is there a way to take use "this" in a second function and have it mean the same thing as in the original? See line 25 where I'm trying to apply a class to the image after clicking an option in the dropdown.

Comment: @kthornbloom what is the `.run`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to update that. New jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kthornbloom/YsW8D/2/ I will eventually have several options in the dropdown. So when you click one of the options, it should do something to the image you're right clicking on.